# I cannot find a way to display "No Results."

Tags: php

The code below works as written provided a name in the database is entered in the search box. If a name not in the data base is entered, the error 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ….. on line 201.' Rather than this generic error I want something like “No Results” to display. Any suggestions anyone? I am aware that this question has been asked before but none of the answers seem to match the type of output I am using here.

```
 enter code here

 <?php 

 include 'connect.php';
 if (isset($_POST['submit-keyword'])) {
     $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
 }  

 try {
     //first pass just gets the column names
     print "<table>";
     $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Bath_Wells_NBR WHERE Founder LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY DATE");

     //return only the first row (we only need field names)
     $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     print " <tr>";

     foreach ($row as $field => $value){
          print " <th>$field</th>";
     } 
     // end foreach
     print " </tr>";


 //second query gets the data
     $data = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Bath_Wells_NBR WHERE Founder LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY DATE");
     $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     foreach($data as $row){
         print " <tr>";
         foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
             print " <td>$value</td>";
         } // end field loop
         print " </tr>";
     } // end record loop
     print "</table>";
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
 } // end try


?>
```

Comment: you should fetch results before attempting to build the table, then its trivial to do `if(empty($result))` or num rows etc also you need to fix the sql injection

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you need to do is make use of the `PDO` object and actually use the prepared statement to avoid sql injection like this:

```
$keyword = '%' . $keyword . '%';
$q = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Bath_Wells_NBR WHERE Founder LIKE :keyword ORDER BY DATE");
$q->bindParam(':keyword',$keyword,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();

//here we will use fetchAll to get the full dataset of results, or an empty array
$result = $q->fetchAll();
```

Now you have `$result` which is an array either of your data, or empty so you can solve your problem by saying:

```
if(count($result) < 1) {
   //output an error message
} else {
   //output your table
}
```

Now you have your solution, let's streamline the code a bit.  Remember, programmers want `DRY` code, so we don't want to do the same query twice.  Lets assume our result count was greater than 0 so we are inside our `else` block.

```
{
    //get all the array keys from the first entry in the result.  These are the column names from the database which we want to use for our headings
    $headings = array_keys($result[0]);

    //now we want to do the same thing to each element, i.e. wrap it in html tags so let's make use of array_walk.  We use the & symbol to pass the values by reference so we can amend them
    array_walk($headings, function(&$field, &$key) {

         $field = <th>$field</th>
    });

   //so now we have an array of table headings, so lets quickly implode them, we don't want to write a whole loop for this
   echo <tr> . implode('',$headings) . </tr>;
```

now you can do your original loop and just output the values hey presto, dryer simpler code!  You could also try and experiment with `array_walk_recursive` and see if you can do the same to the values for your nested loop, after all you just want to wrap them in `<td>` tags!

Note, I've not tested this so code, but you should be able to use it pretty much as it is, just have a little play and experiment with it.

happy coding!

Comment: Thanks jameson2012. Things have gone from bad to worse. All I'm getting now is a plethora of Errors.I'm not particularly interested in streamlining code if it works as it stands (if it ain't broke, don't mend it). Also, should this coding go inside the 'try {' or not? I am not a professional developer (as you might have guessed).